# How to set language in PyFPDF to enable Adobe to read aloud correctly?

Tags: python, pyfpdf

I have a python app that generate PDF documents in the Swedish language. However, the read-aloud function in Adobe think it's English so the result is incomprehensible. When I check the document properties for my PDF there is no language predefined, I assume Adobe then defaults to English.

Is there a way to set the language for a PDF using PyFPDF in python?

Comment: Are you sure Adobe Reader has a Swedish reading voice?

Comment: Well, hmm. I must look that up. Maybe it's Adobe Pro feature?